# Java difference between fixed threadpool and scheduled threadpool

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I have a fixed thread pool that runs 7 concurrent threads at any time (with a queue), and I want to turn it into a scheduled thread pool that runs only 7 concurrent jobs but can queue/schedule more.

Reading the documentation didn't really help me..

[**newFixedThreadPool**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int))

> public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)
>
> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed set of threads operating off
>   a shared unbounded queue. If any thread terminates due to a failure
>   during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if
>   needed to execute subsequent tasks.
>
> Parameters:
>       nThreads - the number of threads in the pool  Returns:
>       the newly created thread pool

[**newScheduledThreadPool**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool(int))

> public static ScheduledExecutorService newScheduledThreadPool(int
>   corePoolSize)
>
> Creates a thread pool that can schedule commands to run after a given
>   delay, or to execute periodically.
>
> Parameters:
>       corePoolSize - the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle.  Returns:
>       a newly created scheduled thread pool

What I don't understand is, are corePoolSize and nThreads the same thing? Is a scheduled thread pool really a subset of a fixed thread pool, meaning that I can use scheduled thread pool as a fixed thread pool that can queue delayed tasks?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want something other than a fixed thread pool? Have you read the javadoc for [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)?

Comment: I am currently using a FixedThreadPool but would like to be able to also schedule tasks after a given delay.. eg. schedule tasks an hour from now, for example. as well as being able to execute immidiately as I am doing today.

Comment: It could've been called a Executors.newFixedScheduledThreadPool(n) but thats alot of letters :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are basically the same thing, just with added scheduling functionality. The ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor even extends the default implementation of the ExecutorService (ThreadPoolExecutor).

nThreads and corePoolSize is the number of threads to be spawned. For a fixed executor, it's always the same. With the other implementation, it varies between min (corePoolSize) and max (maxPoolSize).

Comment: I figured as much, but had to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works that way in JDK5-6.  While in principle the ScheduledExecutorService interface is silent on the issue of pool size, the actual implementation of it used in JDK, uses a fixed pool:

[Class ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

> While this class inherits from
>   ThreadPoolExecutor, a few of the
>   inherited tuning methods are not
>   useful for it. In particular, because
>   it acts as a fixed-sized pool using
>   corePoolSize threads and an unbounded
>   queue, adjustments to maximumPoolSize
>   have no useful effect.

Obviously that may not hold true if you use a different implementation of ScheduledExecutorService provided by an application framework or a different vendor.

Comment: I saw that comment and that's actually what threw me off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are exactly the same with regard to thread pool size: they [ultimately both call](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#SWrQ0LlxhHw/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java) the same [ThreadPoolExecutor constructor](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#SWrQ0LlxhHw/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java&l=1158).